# php tmpdir() alternative to tmpfile()

Tags: php, file-system

[tmpfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile) creates a temporary file which is automatically deleted when php exit. I wanted the same for directories, came up with:

```php
/**
 * create a temporary directory that is automatically deleted when the script exits.
 * 
 * @throws RuntimeException on tmpfile()/mkdir() failure
 * @return string absolute path to the temporary directory
 */
function tmpdir(): string
{
    $max_attempts = 10;
    $attempts = 0;
    for (; $attempts < $max_attempts; ++$attempts) {
        $h = tmpfile();
        if ($h === false) {
            continue;
        }
        $tmpDirPath = stream_get_meta_data($h)['uri'];
        fclose($h);
        // there is technically a (unlikely) race condition between fclose() and mkdir(),
        // that's why i do the weird loop thing
        if (mkdir($tmpDirPath)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($attempts >= $max_attempts) {
        throw new RuntimeException("tmpdir() failed: attempts: " . $attempts . ": error_get_last: " . var_export(error_get_last(), true));
    }
    static $deleteOnExitInstalled = false;
    static $tmpDirPaths = [];
    $tmpDirPaths[] = $tmpDirPath;
    if ($deleteOnExitInstalled === false) {
        register_shutdown_function(function () use (&$tmpDirPaths) {
            $rmdirRecursively = function ($dir) use (&$rmdirRecursively) {
                $children = glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*', GLOB_NOSORT | GLOB_MARK);
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $isChildDir = substr($child, -strlen(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                    if ($isChildDir) {
                        $rmdirRecursively(substr($child, 0, -strlen(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)));
                    } else {
                        unlink($child);
                    }
                }
                rmdir($dir);
            };
            foreach ($tmpDirPaths as $tmpDirPath) {
                $rmdirRecursively($tmpDirPath);
            }
        });
        $deleteOnExitInstalled = true;
    }
    return $tmpDirPath;
}
```

sample usage:

```
$tmpDir = tmpdir();
file_put_contents("{$tmpDir}/test.txt", "Hello World!");
var_dump($tmpDir); // /tmp/phpSyEj2v
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to create a temporary directory? All it could possibly contain are temporary files, but those you can already make. In other words: I am wondering if this is best solution for the problem you're trying to solve, but I don't know what that problem is.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want a temporary directory for a headless Chrome's `--user-data-dir` argument

Comment: OK, I get it. One thing I would do is make deleting a non-empty directory a separate function. It could be useful to a have a function like that, and not have to write one again.

Comment: I see how you are using `static` with `$deleteOnExitInstalled` to control its boolean value after subsequent calls of `tmpdir()`.  Does `$tmpDirPaths` need this same behavior?  It cannot start from scratch each time?  Why not put `$attempts = 0;` in the first parameter of `for()`?  Why not make `$max_attempts = 10` the default parameter of `tmpdir()` to make it more easily customizable?  Trivially, I'd use `sprintf()` with the runtimeException messge to manage the code line length. I might also cache the `strlen()` of the DS.

Comment: @mickmackusa ```Does $tmpDirPaths need this same behavior? It cannot start from scratch each time?``` - yes, the shutdown function use this array to keep track of all the temporary directories created. ```Why not put $attempts = 0; in the first parameter of for()? ``` - in PHP it doesn't really matter, but in many other languages (javascript, C, C++, Rust, just off the top of my head) , variables created in the for loop, goes out of scope outside the for loop, so i have a habit of declaring variables used outside for loops, outside the for loop. (even though it's not required in PHP)

Comment: @mickmackusa ```Why not make $max_attempts = 10 the default parameter of tmpdir() to make it more easily customizable?``` - didn't think of it, that could definitely be added though. ```I might also cache the strlen() of the DS.``` luckily with opcache, there's no need, strlen(string_known_at_compile_time) actually gets compiled to an int at runtime :) check the opcodes under the "VLD" tab here: https://3v4l.org/usfR0/vld  - there's no strlen() in the opcodes, just an int(1)

Answer (score 1):

Found at least 1 bug: if the file contains symlinks, then

> ```
> $isChildDir = substr($child, -strlen(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
> ```

will incorrectly be true, resulting in ***the dir not being cleaned up*** and emitting

> ```
> PHP Warning:  rmdir(/tmp/phpOuCtAg/symlink): Not a directory in foo.php on line x
> ```

The fix seems to be

```php
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $isChildDir = substr($child, -strlen(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                    if ($isChildDir) {
                        $withoutTrailingSlash = substr($child, 0, -strlen(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
                        if (is_link($withoutTrailingSlash)) {
                            unlink($withoutTrailingSlash);
                        } else {
                            $rmdirRecursively($withoutTrailingSlash);
                        }
                    } else {
                        unlink($child);
                    }
                }
```

I think that could probably be shortened further.